# ESP8266 do not send back http resppond

Tags: http, lua, esp8266, send, nodemcu

I have some problem. If I have old firmware (NodeMCU 0.9.5 build 20150318  powered by Lua 5.1.4) then it works and I receive back response to phone. But if I have new one ( build 2022-09-07 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 3.0.1-dev(fce080e)) then I do not receive response (but I get request “who” on ESP8266). What is the problem it could be?

Code:

```lua
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
  conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
    local buf = "";
    buf = buf.."HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n"
    local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
    if(method == nil)then
        _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
    end
    
    local _GET = {}
    if (vars ~= nil)then
        for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
           _GET[k] = v
        end
    end
    
    if(_GET.pin == "ON1")then
        print(“On”)
    elseif(_GET.pin == "OFF1") then
        print(“Off”)
    end
    
    if(_GET.question == "who") then
        buf=""
        buf = buf.."HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n"
        print(buf)
    end
    
    client:send(buf)
    client:close()
    collectgarbage()
    end) 
 end)
```

Comment: `print("On")` and `print(“Off")` have syntax errors - left and right quotation marks in unicode, change to regular quotation marks from the ascii set

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But I have another code there and it "if" does not work, when I send the request "who". The problem is that I don't receive a response with new firmware.

Comment: try to analyze the request, maybe there is some difference in several characters and `find()` does not work and `vars` are not found, etc .

Comment: Thank you. But I enter "if(_GET.question == "who")". "buf" is printed. The problem is that the data is not sent back. I think the problem is in the "client:send(buf)" command in old and new version of firmware, because the same code works in the old version, but not in the new one. And I don't understand how to make it work in the new one.

Comment: client exist? try print(client)

Comment: That's right. I'll try in the evening. Thanks. :)

Comment: Client exist (it shows "userdata: 0x3fff1020" or something). But it shows the same even after "client:close() collectgarbage()".